Why are Christmas items offered in supermarkets as early as late summer?
I hope SE:Economics is the right place to ask this.
It is very common that supermarkets start to sell Christmas items well before the actual holidays and sometimes also decorate the stores accordingly. This year the first Christmas cookies were offered in a local store in late August while there still was a heat wave outside.
I am wondering what the reasoning behind this strategy is. I assume that stores hope to increase profits by setting the mood early on and stretch the period for selling seasonal items.
On the other hand, this practice seems to be received negatively by customers. At best, people ignore it, but I know people who actively boycott this practice and I assume that stores waste a lot of storage and shelf space for items that are not (yet) that much in demand.
So, what is the reasoning behind the premature offering of Christmas products? And does it work as intended or is it just putting off customers? And are there perhaps studies which investigated the effectiveness of this practice?

Christmas is predictable... and the goods sold are storable ...
